# How to install Virtual Treeview?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, virtualtreeview

Virtual treeview by Mike Lischke seems so popular on the web and as third party component. I just downloaded version 4.8.7 on my machine.

I have Delphi 2010 and Delphi 7.0 in 2 partitions.

Aftter clicking installer of virtual treeview, a log file prompts, saying it has been installed successfully.

I check Delphi 2010, yes, it is on component palette showing 3 controls.

But when I start Delphi 7.0, IDE prompts 'Can not load VirtualtreesD7.bpl...'. I ignore it, and find that Virtual treeview design time package is in list but UNCHECKED. If I try to check it, again it promts "Can not load virtualtreesD7...".

I search whole Disk and find a VirtualTreesD7D.bpl, and manually add it in design time package list. It is on palette with 3 controls.

I tested it quickly and exit Delphi 7.0. But when I restart Delphi 7.0, again it prompts "Can not load VirtualtreesD7.bpl...", it is again not on palatte and not Checked in design time package list.

This is very simple question. Can you let me know how to solve it?
Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:

Thanks for comments.

I tested your comments, but not work.

New problem:

If I uninstall virtual treeview by clicking unins000.exe and reinstall it only in Delphi 7.0, the installer prompts in the last screen ''...completed.." and no error prompts. When I start Delphi 7, the virtual treeview design time package is not in package list. This is even worse than the last time (last time it is in package list but not checked).

I check very carefully one line by one line of that log file, it says:

```
...
...
VirtualTreesD7.dpk(39) 
VirtualTreesD7.dpk(39) 
VirtualTreesD7.dpk(41) 
VirtualTreesD7.dpk(43) 

**VirtualTreesD7D.dpk(32) Fatal: Required package 'VirtualTreesD7' not found**
```

Why? 
Why it does not successfully install and does not prompts the error in installation in the last install screen.

How to solve this "Fatal...not found" problem.

Thank you all for help.

New Edit: (Is this Answer?)

Thanks for your help and suggestion first.

I take 2 hours to test and find a possible solution. It works on my machine and it can be installed in Delphi 7.0.

Steps:

```
1. uninstall virtual treeview by clicking unins000.exe from Delphi 7.0 ( you can separately install virtual treeview in Delphi 2010)

2. clicking newly downloaded VirtualTreeview setup 4.8.7.exe, install it in Delphi 7 folder, do not install it in default...Rad..path.  Important: INGNORE ALL ERROR PROMPTS DURING INSTALLATION (INCLUDING ERROR PROMPT IN THAT LARGE INSTALLATION LOG FILE).

3. Go to $\Virtual Treeview, right click VirtualTreesD7D.dpk, select Open with Delphi 32 development environment. A window prompts for you to compile. JUST CLICK COMPILE, DO NOT CLICK INSTALL.

4. Go to Component -> Install Packages. Go to $\Bpl folder and manually add VirtualTreesD7D.bpl into Design Package. The three controls will appear in Palette.

5. Go to folder $\Bpl and YOU MUST COPY VirtualTreesD7.bpl (NOT VirtualTreesD7D.bpl) INTO $\Bin folder.

6. Close Delphi 7 and restart it, you will find that this component is on Palette and in Package list, it is in Design package list and CHECKED.
```

I personally feel that the installer of Virtual treeview needs improvements to free users from such trouble and test in installation. The installer needs rewrite.

This is my case of installation.  I do not know if it can be generalized to all users.

Thank you all.

Comment: I have this problem too, never did find a solution..

Comment: Have you tried to install each version in the separate directory such as ..\lib\VirtualTreeView ? I've had a similar problem and this helped me. But before you do it, uninstall all previous versions.

Comment: Sorry, I meaned install VT for each Delphi version in a separate directory.

Comment: @Warren: Regarding your edit: Read my answer. VirtualTreesD7D isn't finding VirtualTreesD7. In other words, the design time package can't find the run time package.

Comment: @Ken: I tested your answer, added all related virtualtree folder path to library path and browsing path in Tools-Environment Options-library. But can not solve it. The problem is a little more complicated when I install virtual treeview in Delphi 2010 and Delphi 7 at the same time.

Comment: @Ken: continued -- ( it can not be installed in delphi 7, and the installer does NOT indicate such). If I try to install it only in Delphi 7, it stilll can not be installed (In log file: it prompts VirtualTreesD7D.dpk(32) Fatal: Required package 'VirtualTreesD7' not found). So in both cases, it can not be installed in Delphi 7. Maybe there are previous versions that can be installed in Delphi 7.

Comment: @Ken: and Thank you so much for comments and possible answer.

Comment: IMHO the installation works fine. I've had two versions of Delphi on my computer and I ran it twice - for each version separately. I also used Delphi's own directory ..\lib\VirtualTreeView for each version. And of course I've had checked "Search path" as well as "Browsing path" check boxes on the 5th page of the wizard.

Comment: @daemon_x, Please let me know what folder is that VirtualTreesD7.bpl in after you set up in Delphi 7.  I am running the version 4.8.7 for several times. For each time, it prompts Can not load package VirtualTreesD7. though I also checked and unchecked search path and browsing path. What VT version are you running. Now is that I manually put it into Bin folder, it works. If not in that folder, it always prompts error. So where is your VirtualTreesD7.bpl after you setup.

Comment: I'm using the same version 4.8.7. For D2009 is the design time part saved on my machine here as c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl\VirtualTreesD12.bpl, and the similar will be also for D7 (I can't check that now), but I'm using Win 7, so there might be some differences bewteen other windows versions. And this might be the problem (I can't verify this too), let's say you've got the same path as me, but your Delphi with Windows other than Vista or 7 doesn't take a look there (because it's some public documents place).

Comment: I remember, that when I installed Delphi 2009 for the first time on Win 7, I had to let the installation wizard to create this public folder and Delphi then remembers when to look for the stuff like this. And if your VT compiles that *.bpl library here, then the problem is really that your Delphi don't know where to look for that, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: Hey Warren. Could you please copy your edit with your solution in, post it as an answer, and accept it? That way this question will drop off the "Unanswered Questions" list. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE uses LoadLibrary (actually, LoadPackage) to load packages for components that are installed. This means that it follows the same logic for where it looks for files that LoadLibrary does.

The problem is that the IDE can't find the package using LoadLibrary's search logic - see the [Remarks section here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx). So the solution is to add the folder to Delphi's Library Path (Tools->Options->Environment Options->Delphi Options->Library - Win32), or move it somewhere on the system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the folder where the virtualtrees.pas (\source) is located in the environment search path.

You may manually need to install the *.dpk file for Delphi 7. Open the D7.dpk, compile then open and install the D7D.dpk (Runtime first then Designtime package)
Haven't done it on Delphi2010 w/ Delphi7, but installing with just Delphi7 is fine.

*edited

Comment: You've got it backwards. :-) The designtime package will depend on the runtime package, so the runtime package has to be built first. The runtime package does not get installed, though; only the designtime package.

Comment: Thanks Ken, Updated. Also i would check daemon_x's comments about separate install dirs.